# ASP.NET Web API Delete returns 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5, http-delete

Using ASP.NET (4.6.1) Web Api on my local IIS 7.5 I'm trying to call a delete method:

```
[HttpDelete]
[Route("Values/")]
public IHttpActionResult DeleteValue(int id)
{         
    return Ok();
}
```

Following DELETE request works perfectly fine:

`https://localhost/api/Values?id=22`

But, I would like to call DELETE request like this:

`https://localhost/api/Values/22`

This gives me: `404.0 — Not Found`

My api route config is defined like:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

My web.config looks like:

```
 <system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <remove name="WebDAV" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
<modules>
  <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>
```

Do I missed something?

Comment: Change route to: `[Route("Values/{id}")]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update your route to

```
[Route("Values/{id}")]
```

So that it can map the request correctly to your method.